# Not understanding return behavior in python

Tags: python

I was just trying a simple code:

```
import sys

def main():
    print "this is main"
    return "string1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

And when I run this piece of code, it gives random result, sometimes "string1" before "this is main" and sometimes after it.

Why is it so?

2 sample outputs:

> this is main
>
> string1
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

============

> string1
>
> this is main
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: How is that even printed? Why would `sys.exit()` take a string as a parameter?

Comment: @cricket_007 See the documentation of `sys.exit` https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: @timarko - My question was directed towards OP, not so much my lack of understanding

Comment: A full answer will depend on several factors not mentioned in the question: what operating system are you using, how are you running the program, and where are standard output and standard error being directed (although it looks like the answer to the last question is a terminal). All of these affect how the standard output and standard error are buffered (if at all).

Comment: @chepner , I am using win64 OS. And Yes it looks like stdout and stderr buffering is the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.exit` takes the return value of `main()` and produces it as the error code of the application. The value should usually be numeric, though Python is being a bit tricky here.

From the documentation of [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20exit#sys.exit):

> If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing
>   zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit
>   code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick
>   way to exit a program when an error occurs.

So what may be happening is a race between flushing of `stdout` (for `print`) and the output to `stderr` as specified above.

I suggest you try to flush `stdout` after the `print` (`sys.stdout.flush`) and see if you get consistent output that way.

Comment: See the documentation of `sys.exit` https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: @EliBendersky Thanks. I got the idea behind this behavior. I tried sys.stdout.flush() after print statement, but still same behavior.

Comment: @prateekgoyal: I'd recommend against relying on buffering order of the different streams. Don't pass strings to `sys.exit`